# How do I set Windows 10's folder view settings to General Items for all folders?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I've tried things like selecting a drive or root folder and going to Customize and setting Optimize The Folder to General Items and checking the checkbox that says "Also apply this template to all subfolders".

However it has no effect. Folders with pictures still display as thumbnails, folders with music get the Title/Artist/Track number columns, and so on. The only thing that works is going to a specific folder and setting it to General Items. But I am not about to do that for every single folder. The other issue is it saves the folder view preference in a desktop.ini file. I'd rather not litter my drives with desktop.ini files for every folder.

Can I not set General Items to be the setting for all folders with that setting stored once, in a single location? Would this work via a Powershell script or something?

Answer (score 4):

This script seems to have worked:

```
@echo off

REG ADD “HKCU\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell” /V FolderType /T REG_SZ /D NotSpecified /F

taskkill /f /im explorer.exe

start explorer.exe
```

Comment: This worked for Windows 11 too.
This would be the PowerShell script to do the same thing:
`New-ItemProperty 'HKCU:\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\' -Name FolderType -PropertyType string -Value NotSpecified -Force`